# Docker install php5.6 and lighttpd on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, linux, docker, ubuntu, lighttpd

Due to the EOL of Ubuntu 14.04, I am trying to migrate from 14.04 to 16.04.
Unfortunately, 16.04 LTS supports php 7 by default and our code base is written in PHP 5.
The libraries related to PHP 5 such as php5-cgi php5-mysql php5-curl are not supported any more on Xenial.
Hence I am trying to use PHP 5.6 so that there is no change to the code for the moment.

My Docker file has the below code which installs only lighttpd and php5.6.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -y

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
```

## install php5.6 and web server

```
RUN apt-get purge `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' | tr "\n" " "` \
    && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
    && LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove ubuntu-core-launcher \
    && apt-get install -y lighttpd php5.6 php5.6-fpm php5.6-cgi

RUN apt-get install -y vim net-tools

RUN mkdir /srv/app && mkdir /srv/run

WORKDIR /srv/app

ADD . /srv/app
```

## change permissions for lighttpd files

```
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/log/lighttpd && chmod -R 777 /var/cache/lighttpd && chmod -R 775 /srv/run
RUN touch /srv/run/lighttpd.pid && chmod 777  /srv/run/lighttpd.pid
```

## lighttpd config

```
RUN sed -i -e "s/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/g" /etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini

RUN sed -i -e "s/server.document-root/#server.document-root/g" /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf \
    && sed -i -e 's/\/var\/run\/lighttpd.pid/\/srv\/run\/lighttpd.pid/g' /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf \
    && sed -i -e "s/80/8888/g" /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf \
    && echo "server.document-root = \"/srv/app\"" >> /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf \
    && echo "server.network-backend = \"writev\"" >> /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf \
    && echo "server.modules += (\"mod_fastcgi\")" >> /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf

EXPOSE 8888

ENTRYPOINT ["lighttpd", "-D", "-f", "/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf"]
```

Run command: docker run -d  -p 8888:8888 test-image:4.0

I have an index.html – Hello world code in my working folder and after I run, I am able to get the index.html on my localhost:8888/index.html
I also have an index.php that displays phpinfo() and when I try localhost:8888/index.php, I get a 403 Forbidden error.

I also tried adding the below lines in the Dockerfile,

```
RUN mv /etc/lighttpd/conf-available/15-fastcgi-php.conf /etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled

RUN sed -i -e "s/php-cgi/php-cgi5.6/g" /etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/15-fastcgi-php.conf
```

After build and run the server exits immediately, 
docker ps -a gives the status as Exited(0).

It would be helpful if anyone can help me figure out how to make my php code run with this docker configuration.
Thanks.

Comment: [PHP 5.6 is also EOL](http://php.net/supported-versions.php); you might looking into upgrading that too.  The other universal suggestion if a container is exiting immediately is to launch it without `-d` and see if there's anything interesting in the logs.

Comment: Hi @David Maze, yes we also have PHP upgrade in the pipeline. But, currently we need something working with 5.6 as a temporary fix. Any suggestion on the dockerfile above? I did run without  `-d` but there was no log and the server just exited.